# How to Pass Windows Credentials with Report Viewer for an external image call

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

We have a Report that calls an external image that is hosted on a server that requires Windows Credentials. How do we setup Report Server to pass the Credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if the report is running as the logged in user, and that user has access to the external image it should work.

Otherwise you might have to create a generic user to run the report as that has access to the remote image.

If that fails your probably into creating a bit of custom code to go and grab the image and place it on the report.

One question i have to ask is if its just an image can you not just copy it of the external server and host it locally?